# OMXplayer problem from UDP

Tags: video, streaming-video

I'm streaming a video from a linux pc, with avconv:

```
avconv -re -i video.mov -c:v libx264 -f mpegts udp://raspIP:1234
```

And from my rasp I'm trying to view this video

```
omxplayer -i udp://linuxIP:1234
```

But I get this errors:

```
[h264 @ 0x1de4180] non-existing PPS referenced
[h264 @ 0x1de4180] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x1de4180] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x1de4180] no frame!
[mpegts @ 0x1dcab90] decoding for stream 0 failed
[mpegts @ 0x1dcab90] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 0x1dcab90] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
```

Any help?

Comment: I solved.. problem was the "-i" option!